# UniqueName of telerik GridDataItem changed on rebinding

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, datatable, telerik, radgrid

We have a scenario where different format of csv needs to show data in RadGrid.
Format 1 needs to show 4 columns (as format 1 csv file have 4 columns, id, fName, lName, age, city)
Format 2 needs to show 5 columns (as format 2 csv file have 5 columns, id, fName, lName, age, state, zip)
To bind data, we create a datatable and add columns as per selected format,  and add additional Hidden column, which decide the BackColor of grid row. Once user select file and click load button, it check all user ids if exists in database. Once a record match, it change the backcolor of that row.

Issue I faced is, we earlier had same number of columns for format 1 and 2. And it worked fine. Since we have changed the number of columns, it start changing the uniquename of hidden columns (from IsMatch to IsMatch1) when we first load csv of format 1 and then load csv for format 2. Following exception occurred on Rebinding:
Cannot find a cell bound to column name

To Hide column, we use following code:

```
protected void rdg_ColumnCreated(object sender, GridColumnCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Column.Display = !this.InvisibleColumns.Contains(e.Column.UniqueName);
}
```

Back ground color that throws exception copied below:

```
protected void rdg_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
        var matched = NullableHelper.TryParseBoolean(item["IsMatch"].Text);
        if (matched.HasValue && !matched.Value)
            item.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(249, 79, 79);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing research for whole day, I manage to fix it using following hack: (still not sure why setting datasource = null before rebind keep items.count > 0)

```
protected void rgUploadResults_ColumnCreated(object sender, GridColumnCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    //uniquename of invisible columns disturb on rebinding
    if (this.InvisibleColumns != null)
    {
        int colIndex = this.InvisibleColumns.FindIndex(
            x => e.Column.UniqueName.Contains(x) //when unique name contains extra characters in invisible columns on rebinding
            && e.Column.UniqueName != x //no need to replace unique name when it exactly matches
        );
        if (colIndex > -1)
        {
            e.Column.UniqueName = this.InvisibleColumns[colIndex];
        }
    }

    e.Column.Display = this.InvisibleColumns != null && !this.InvisibleColumns.Contains(e.Column.UniqueName);
}
```